# angular ng-repeat displaying object items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having a problem with displaying a JSON array objects that I have gotten from a async http request.

I have used ng-repeat to try and display the objects in the view but I am having no luck after many hours. Here is the code I have so far.

**index.html**

```
<div class="main" ng-controller = "MyController">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in parks">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>{{item.parks.name}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.parks.park_size}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.parks.open_times}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.parks.days_closed}}<h2>
    <img ng-src="images/{{item.parks.short}}.jpg">
  </div>
</li>
```

**controllers.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.parks = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "parks": [
        {
      "park_name": "Central Park",
      "park_size": {
                "miles": "1.2",
                "meters": "1900"
            },
      "open_times": {
                "Monday-Friday": "8am-10pm",
                "Saturday-Sunday": "10am-6.30pm"
            },
            "days_closed": [
                "December 25th",
                "December 26th"
            ],

      "images": [
                {
                    "short": "centralimage1.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    "short": "centralimage2.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    "short": "centralimage3.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    "short": "centralimage4.jpeg"
                }
            ]
        },
    {
      "park_name": "Riverside Park",
      "park_size": {
                "miles": "0.2",
                "meters": "320"
            },
      "open_times": {
                "Monday-Friday": "7am-9pm",
                "Saturday-Sunday": "9am-8.30pm"
            },
            "days_closed": [
                "December 25th",
                "December 26th",
        "Jamuary 1st"
            ],

      "images": [
                {
                    "short": "riversideimage1.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    "short": "riversideimage2.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    "short": "riversideimage3.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    "short": "riversideimage4.jpeg"
                }
            ]
        }





    ]
}
```

JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/owxwh0kz/

Comment: Please create JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: @TomePejoski https://jsfiddle.net/owxwh0kz/

Comment: @D Weir, please find the working version in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40965242/2106876. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over parks already, so your code can look like this

```
<li ng-repeat="item in parks">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>{{item.park_name}}<h2>
```

(I changed item.park.name to be item.park_name to match your data)

Otherwise check using the Angular inspector to see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data coming back from the json object is not consitent with your binding selectors. Inside an `ng-repeat` you are alreading interating over the scope of `parks`.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in parks">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>{{item.park_name}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.park_size}}<h2> 
    <h2>{{item.open_times}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.days_closed}}<h2>
```

For the images because they are in another array you would have to performn another repeat to grab all images.Note that nested `ng-repeats` can lead to negative performance impacts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you should iterate over `parks.parks` to reach the array of the `$scope.parks` object.

Also, within the `ng-repeat` you should use `item.*` instead of `item.parks.*`

Here is JSFiddle with the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/x0ja420L/

Answer (score 0):

**Some code changes has been made in your code :**

- Proper closing of the HTML tags to work it properly.

Use `<h2>{{item.park_name}}</h2>` instead of `<h2>{{item.park_name}}<h2>`

- `ng-repeat` directive iterate the array object so if you want to access `park_name` you have to use `ng-repeat` like this `ng-repeat="item in parks.parks"`

## [demo !](https://jsfiddle.net/owxwh0kz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` directive iterate the array object, so if you want to access park_name you have to use `ng-repeat` like this `ng-repeat="item in parks.parks"`,code should like this

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in parks.parks">
  <div class="info">
    <h2>{{item.park_name}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.park_size}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.open_times}}<h2>
    <h2>{{item.days_closed}}<h2>
    <img ng-src="images/{{item.images[0].short}}.jpg">
  </div>
</li>
```

you can see the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/owxwh0kz/2/)